# SP07 - Open a pdf file in new tab on IE

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, office-integration, pdf

I want to open pdf file in new tab and visualize it.

**This is my code :**

```
SPLinkButton linkHelp = new SPLinkButton();
linkHelp.Text = "HELP...";
linkHelp.Target = "_blank";
linkHelp.Click += new EventHandler(linkHelp_Click);
```

**This is my button event:**

```
void linkHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string path = @"http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/UserGiude-WayBill.pdf";
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
   if (buffer != null)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
       HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
   }     
}
```

**This is a error:**

[image]

With hyperLink This code download the file(with IE)... I want Open a file in new tab... this is possible with **IE Edge..**, How to do this with IE ?

```
HyperLink href = new HyperLink();
    href.NavigateUrl = "http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Shared%20Documents/UserGiude-WayBill%20System.pdf";
    href.Text = "Помощ...";
    href.Target = "_blank";
```

Comment: You can change the setting for document library to open document in browser.

Comment: From where do this?

Comment: Please check here...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: is that works for you?

Comment: Have you got the solution? is my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using **`SPLinkButton`**?

You can simply use **`HyperLink`** with its attribute called   **`Navigateurl`** from your code.

You can follow below steps in below mentioned URL.

[Open PDF files from a Document Library in a New Window](https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2011/02/21/open-pdf-files-from-a-document-library-in-a-new-window/)

**Follow this**

1. Open IIS manager (Start | Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Internet Information Services Manager).
2. Expand the “Application Pools” node.
3. Right click the application pool which your project is using, and then select “Properties”.
4. Click “Identity” tab.
5. Choose “Local System” in the Predefined dropdown list.

About how to grant permission to a file, please check these steps:

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Right click the file, and then select "Properties".
3. Click the "Security" tab.
4. Add "Network Service" in access list and check "Modify", "Read", and "Write" for it.

and finally

**in your code add this**

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Webservicetest1/Service.asmx/webmrthod");

request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

**Remember that below lines are important for you**

```
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

It is working without any problem..

Comment: Add only this in your question i my code ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: See my code below...